# SSAS and Power BI - The session ID cannot be found. Either the session does not exist or it has already expired

Tags: powerbi, azure-analysis-services

When using Excel Pivot Table that's connected to Azure Analysis Services (or Power BI), some users sometimes encounter an error like below.

[image]

```
The session ID cannot be found. Either the session does not exist or it has already expired
```

Usually it happens after a period of inactivity even without performing any actions or having Excel in the foreground. Clicking OK usually "resets" the session and connection and things are fine.

But it's distracting. In theory it should just lose the session silently and then resume the session or modal window if some action is performed.

plenty of posts on Microsoft's site:

- https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Query/Session-ID-cannot-be-found/td-p/1082094
- https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Query/Session-ID-cannot-be-found/td-p/742347

Answer (score -1):

I use Azure Analysis Service and I also face the same situation. There are two known solutions for me. (Pls chose this as answer if it works for you)

1. Restart the Visual studio - I used to do this till I found better option.
2. In Visual Studio, go to the Model explorer tab, and under Data sources, rt click the data source and select 'Change Source'. On popup screen (Who uses popup as a word? - I still remember Foxpro :) ), click ok button. This will reconnect to the server and create a new session.

[image: Tabular Model Explorer]

[image: Popup screen]